# Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Please could someone help me with this error? I have actually been really struggling to find solid, simple examples for SQLAlchemy. Whilst there are plenty of Model examples of there is not much examples of how to use these Models.

The Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: 
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Species.sc_genus
- there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  
Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

The Code

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relation

Base = declarative_base()


class Genus(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'genus'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    common_name = Column(String)
    scientific_name = Column(String)
    sc_sub_family = "sc_sub_family"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Genus(common_name='%s')>" % (self.scientific_name)


# Species is a child of Genus
class Species(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'species'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    common_name = Column(String)
    scientific_name = Column(String)
    sc_genus = relation("Genus", backref="species")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Species(common_name='%s')>" % (self.scientific_name)


def addSpecies(session):

    species = Species()
    species.common_name = "House Cat"
    species.scientific_name = "Felis catus"


    genus = Genus()
    genus.scientific_name = "Felis"
    session.add(genus)

    species.sc_genus = genus

    session.add(species)
    session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

    ## A bunch of stuff to make the connection to the database work.
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foos.db', echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    addSpecies(session)
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship

Comment: What are you hoping to represent with `sc_sub_family = "sc_sub_family"`?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to specify a foreign key for the relationship.

```
class Genus(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'genus'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    scientific_name = Column(String)
    # sc_sub_family = "sc_sub_family"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Genus(common_name='%s')>" % (self.scientific_name)


# Species is a child of Genus
class Species(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'species'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    common_name = Column(String)
    scientific_name = Column(String)
    sc_genus = relation("Genus", backref="species")
    sc_genus_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('genus.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Species(common_name='%s')>" % (self.scientific_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was adding the primaryjoin info as it requests in the err msg.

```py
    sc_genus = relationship(
        "Genus", backref="species",
        primaryjoin="Genus.id == Species.genus_id"
    )
```